# 101 basic ruby/sinatra: undefined variable 'session'

Tags: ruby, sinatra

app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
    enable :sessions

    if session[:user_id].nil? then
        erb :login
    end
end

require_relative 'routes/init.rb'
```

config.ru:

```
require './app'
run MyApp
```

Running `shotgun config.ru` or `thin start -R config.ru` yields:

```
app.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `session' for main:Object (NameError)
```

This is very 101ish. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you don't have that code within a `get` block or something similar. Basically, sinatra will only know about the `session` object in the context of a request. Something like this would work for the root url:

```
require 'sinatra'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Application
  enable :sessions

  get '/' do
    if session[:user_id].nil? then
      erb :login
    end
  end
end
```